# multiple model not load in same controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

i want to run multiple model in same controller but its show below error

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: Home::$Company
>
> Filename: controllers/Home.php
>
> Line Number: 23

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct ();

        $this->load->model('Product');
        $this->load->model('Company');
        //$this->load->model(array('Product','Company'));


    }
    public function index()
    {

        $Product = $this->Product->getProduct(10);
        if($Product)
        {
            $data['Product'] = $Product;
        }
        $Company = $this->Company->getCompany(10);
        if($Company)
        {
            $data['Company'] = $Company;

        }
        $this->load->view('Home',$data);

    }
}
```

//Company Model

```
class Company extends CI_Controller {


    function getCompany($limit=null,$start=0)
    {
        $data = array();
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM user as u,category as c,sub_category as sc WHERE c.Category_Id=u._Category_Id and u._Sub_Category_Id=sc.Sub_Category_Id ORDER by rand() limit '.$start.','.$limit);
        $res   = $query->result();        
        return $res;
    }
    function getOneCompany($id)
    {
        $this->db->where('User_Id',$id);
        $query = $this->db->get('user');
        $res = $query->result();
        return $res;
    }
}
```

// Product model

```
class Product extends CI_Controller {


    function getProduct($limit=null,$start=0)
    {
        $data = array();
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM product as p,user as u,category as c,sub_category as sc WHERE p._User_Id = u.User_Id and  c.Category_Id=u._Category_Id and u._Sub_Category_Id=sc.Sub_Category_Id ORDER by rand() limit '.$start.','.$limit);
        $res   = $query->result();        
        return $res;
    }
    function getOneProduct($id)
    {
        $this->db->where('User_Id',$id);
        $query = $this->db->get('user');
        $res = $query->result();
        return $res;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are your Product and Company models extending CI_Model?

Comment: Yes Product and Company both are present under model folder.

Comment: and also both are working without error if i comment any one model load.
But when i call Both model then display error.

Comment: Can you show use the top couple of lines from each of the models please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your models start with

`class Company extends CI_Controller {`

They should be

`class Company extends CI_Model {`

---

<strike>Try changing</strike>

```
$this->load->model('Product');
$this->load->model('Company');
```

to

```
$this->load->model('product');
$this->load->model('company');
```

notice the lower case model names.  Just tried it here and got the same error as you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$models = array(
    'menu_model' => 'mmodel',
    'user_model' => 'umodel',
    'admin_model' => 'amodel',
);
foreach ($models as $file => $object_name)
{
    $this->load->model($file, $object_name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Please do not only leave some code, but also explain a bit what it does. The code might seem trivial for you, but the question author will appreciate it nonetheless!

Comment: can you tell me which file i need to write this code.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving a name to you model :

```
$this->load->model('Company', 'Company');
```